# Why isn't this working on Python? It keeps saying 12 even though the largest number is 15

Tags: python

The largest number is 15, but it prints 12. Help?

```
nums = [12, 7, 8, 15, 2, 10, 3]

big = nums[0]

spot = 0

while spot == len(nums):
    spot = spot + 1
    if(nums[spot] > big):
        big = nums[spot]
print big
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Well, what's not working?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? What have you tried? Why isn't it working?

Comment: `spot == len(nums)` is always false.

Answer (score 2):

Because your termination condition for the loop does not make sense.  You will never go into the loop, because `spot == len(nums)` is not true at the start of the loop!

Have another think about the condition when you want the while loop to exit - it should be true initially, and become false when you've reached the end of your list.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `enumerate()` here, and iterate over `nums[1:]`:

```
In [5]: nums = [12, 7, 8, 15, 2, 10, 3]

In [6]: big = nums[0]

In [7]: for i,x in enumerate(nums[1:],1):
   ...:     if x>big:
   ...:         big=x
   ...:         spot=i
   ...:         

In [8]: spot
Out[8]: 3

In [9]: big
Out[9]: 15
```

`help()` on `enumerate()`:

> enumerate(iterable[, start]) -> iterator for index, value of iterable
>
> Return an enumerate object.  iterable must be another object that
>   supports iteration.  The enumerate object yields pairs containing a
>   count (from start, which defaults to zero) and a value yielded by the
>   iterable argument. enumerate is useful for obtaining an indexed list:
>       (0, seq[0]), (1, seq[1]), (2, seq[2]), ...

Comment: ok, just completely wondering, where does the `In [5]:` come from? I've seen it before but I have no idea what it is. Is this some other version of the Python interpreter or something?

Answer (score 1):

`while spot == len(nums):`

Since `spot` is 0 and `len(nums)` is 7 this will never be true. You meant `!=` instead of `==` I believe.

This looks cleaner:

```
for i in nums:
 if i > big:
  big = i
print big
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just do

```
nums = [12, 7, 8, 15, 2, 10, 3]
big = max(nums)
spot = nums.index(big)
```